# htaccess problem in https url codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, vhosts, .htaccess

I am having problem in my htaccess file. Would someone help me to identify the problem. 
I actually removed the index.php in

> foldername/application/config/config.php

I added this in vhost of my apache and restarted services

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@mai.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/server/Apache24/htdocs/foldername"
    <Directory "C:/server/Apache24/htdocs/foldername">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>   
    ServerName https://foldername.com
    ServerAlias https://foldername.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

This works actually on my localhost, but when I configure the url, I added https because I need it to be in https, the htaccess doesn't work.

Here's my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `index.php` you mention is not really relevant and is not typically used.  Since you mention it, maybe you are working somewhere unexpected.  Why did you remove it, what was the goal?  Where is your `.htaccess` file now?

Comment: Also, why do you have the `application` RewriteRule in there?  What are you trying to do?  The standard Codeigniter set up is to have your DocumentRoot pointing at your `public_html` directory.

Comment: Adding index.php is not my goal. I want to remove it permanently since I am using controller / view.. Yes I noticed that, and I tried the htaccess provided in codeigniter website but still doesn't work. I was thinking that https is not be seen on my htaccess. I don't know how to configure it for https://foldername.com

Comment: Controller and view have nothing to do with whether `index.php` is present or not. As to removing it - you cannot remove `public_html/index.php`, that is what handles every request.  Maybe you mean you want to remove it from the URL?  I'm still not sure why you deleted an (unrelated) `index.php`, nor where your `.htaccess` file is.  Maybe take a step back and go over the installation and setup docs for CI, it is quite straightforward - they also document how to remove `index.php` from the URL.  I'd suggest leaving https out of it until you have http set up and working.

Comment: Hi, I removed index.php in config because in url,  I don't need to type /index.php/ on it. I just want the url directly be connected to http s://sample.com/con/vi  . Just like that. If I do that, I got an error and the page return to 404. BUT when I enter this in my url, http s://sample.com/index.php/conf/vi, it works and the page load. I need someone can help me how can i do / update my  htaccess when my url will starts by https, and doesnt need to enter index.php in url.

Comment: As I said - 1) `config/index.php` is not related; 2) web server DocumentRoot should be `public_html/`; 3) [the documentation describes how to remove index.php](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html) from your URLs; 4) you still didn't tell me where your `.htaccess` is - it should be in `public_html/`, where `index.php` is; 5) I suggest you take a step back and re-read installation and configuration docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/index.html), it is straightforward and you seem to have taken a wrong turn. 6) Leave https until you have http working.